# XSL stylesheet gives error when there are two same namespace but different attributes

Tags: xml, xslt

As the title says I get an error when having this

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:openSearch="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearchrss/1.0/"
xmlns:openSearch="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/">
```

I tried to add them both with a comma `,` but I got the same result like

`xmlns:openSearch="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearchrss/1.0/,http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/"`

Is there any way to include both ?

Comment: Someone is scared to tell the reason of -1 !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's not allowed.  The purpose of namespace declarations (`xmlns:[prefix]="[namespace-uri]"`) is to define a mapping from prefix to namespace-uri.

If there are two values, the mapping is ambiguous and could not be used to figure out for some element `<openSearch:element />` which namespace uri to attach to the element.

Comment: I see... I am using XSLT to transform/format a document. Is it possible to replace that with something like `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>` ?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do.  You want to replace something with an XML declaration, but what is it?

Answer (score 2):

You need to assign unique prefixes, for example:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:openSearch10="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearchrss/1.0/"
    xmlns:openSearch11="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/">
```